# How to deal with a variable that may be one of several types

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a function like this

```
sqlQuery(query : string | Array, database = 'swdata') : Promise {
    let rest;
    if (Array.isArray(query)) {
        rest = query.splice(1);
        query = sqlString.format(query[0], rest);
    }

    const request = new Request('data', 'sqlQuery', {database, query, formatValues: true});
    return this.connection.sendRequest(request);

}
```

My IDE complains that there is no method splice for a string. Is that just a quirk with my IDE, or is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: And rightfully so, splice is from [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) not string

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to cast query to Array: `rest = (query as Array).splice(1);`.

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Isac I understand, that is why the type check is there. `if(Array.isArray(query))`

Comment: `Array.isArray(string)` is supposed to return false, as per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). Is the code entering the `if` ?

Comment: Which IDE you are using? Your IDE is not using TypeScript language service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDE does not properly support TypeScript Language Service.

`Array.isArray()` is a Type Guard function that participates in the control flow analysis of TypeScript. That means in that block, TypeScript Language Service can determine that the type of `query` is of type array and you should not see the error.

For example, if your IDE is WebStorm, you need to go to setting and check using TypeScript language service.
Other IDE may have similar options or plugins.

You can use VSCode to test it out. It should be working just fine.